# jQuery.focus not working in I.E 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, focus

I want to get `focus` on an `anchor tag` from the `URL`

**Anchor tag**

```
<a id='714895'>&nbsp;</a>
```

**URL**

http://test.com/sites/alzheimers-disease-early-detection.aspx?ShowAllComments=True#714895

**jQuery Code**

```
 try
{
if(document.URL.indexOf("?ShowAllComments=True#") >= 0){
var elementClicked = "#" +location.href.split('#')[1];
$("elementClicked").focus();
}
catch(e)
{alert(e.message);}
```

Also tried

```
 try
{
if(document.URL.indexOf("?ShowAllComments=True#") >= 0){
var elementClicked = "#" +location.href.split('#')[1];
$("elementClicked").focus().focus();
}
catch(e)
{alert(e.message);}
```

And

```
 try
{
if(document.URL.indexOf("?ShowAllComments=True#") >= 0){
setTimeout(function(){
var elementClicked = "#" +location.href.split('#')[1];
$("elementClicked").focus();},100);
}
}
catch(e)
{alert(e.message);}
```

Code works perfectly on `Firefox` and `Chrome` but does not work in `I.E`.
Any other way or modifications should be done to work it in I.E too..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ 
var elementClicked = "#"+location.href.split('#')[1]; 
$('#elementClicked').focus(); }, 100);
```

IE 11 time to focus the other control and then steal the focus and add it to elementClicked.

Otherwise try this one.

```
try { 
function elementFocus(e){
if(document.URL.indexOf("?ShowAllComments=True#") >= 0){ 
var elementClicked = "#" +location.href.split('#')[1];
$("elementClicked").focus(); 
e.preventDefault(); 
} 
} 
catch(e){alert(e.message);}
```